# Sort alphabetically

Tags: excel, sorting

I have a column with multiple value, I want to sort the name alphabetically, how do I sort it? Example:- This is how it look now.

```
Name                                       |  Code  |  Status

Amanda, Bryan, Zoey, Albert, Macro, Johnny | 33     | Active
Amanda, Bryan, Zoey, Albert, Jeniffer, Mac | 44     | Active
```

Answer (score 0):

Easiest is to do this in VBA. Create the following 2 functions in a VBA module:

```vb
Public Function fSort(vValue As String, vDelimiter As String) As String
    'Take a string, split it into an array based on the delimiter,
    'sort it and finally convert it back into a string

    fSort = Join(fSortArray(Split(vValue, vDelimiter)), vDelimiter)

End Function

Function fSortArray(vArray As Variant) As Variant
    'Sort a one dimensional array of string values alphabetically

    Dim vI As Long, vJ As Long
    Dim vTmp As String

    For vI = 0 To UBound(vArray)
        For vJ = vI To UBound(vArray)
            If UCase(vArray(vJ)) < UCase(vArray(vI)) Then
                vTmp = vArray(vI)
                vArray(vI) = vArray(vJ)
                vArray(vJ) = vTmp
            End If
        Next
    Next

    fSortArray = vArray
End Function
```

Then use `fSort` in a cell formula like:

```
=fSort(A3,", ")
```